# how to get the loss tensor of the first batch in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

To implement the grad norm method in this paper [https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.02257], I need to calculate **loss_i/loss_0**, where **loss_i** is the loss of ith step.

Now the question is how to store the **loss_0** into a tensor?

Comment: your question is not clear. Output of loss function is tensor already

Comment: thanks for ur comment! "Output of loss function" is changing with the training data, and what I want is the loss of the first batch of training data.

Comment: 'if step==0:
  loss_0 = loss'

Comment: okey, very concise solution. I have thought of it too, but I'm not sure whether loss_0 will keep changing with loss during training. 
I'll take a try~ thank you